# i want the android code for playing two videos at a time full code

Tags: android

i want full code please can any one provide me code?

Comment: what do you mean by previous and next page boundaries??

Comment: This is a page for problems. You can ask something you are stuck with. But this is not a "giveMeTheCode"-Page.

Comment: Android developer forum gives an example for view pager http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html

Comment: ... and I want a pony ...

Comment: Use this and code it yourself http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888

Comment: thank you for providing the url

Answer (score 0):

I think you do not have any ideas about it.But here you can not ask for code. You can ask for some help to find the way to solve the problem.To play two videos at a time, you can use to two videoviews for each video.

Comment: so can any one provide some urls according to this